# Should XAMPP be installed on an actual physical Server?

Tags: server, xampp, backend

Is XAMPP just meant for testing and setting up virtual servers ?(cause that's what wiki say)
Can it be installed on an actual physical server? Do developers actually do that? 
I'm a little confused cause if it were true, why would anyone install a virtual server on a physical server? It's like trying to run Excel on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAMPP simulates a typical stack used for web development on a local machine. If you have access to an actual physical server, you would typically install things like the web server (such as Apache) and MySQL on the server itself. The developers of XAMPP consider it more of a development tool due to certain features being disabled to make dev easier.

Virtualisation in servers is used because the actual physical machines are very powerful and so are idling a large amount of time. Putting those resources to use by creating two virtual servers on top of the host reduces cost and increases operational throughput.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual server and Docker can be used to test with different environments at the same time, or test beta software for future releases. On Maschines that have 6 or 8 cores and running 3.6 Millions instructions per second, there are plenty of resources to have more than 1 maschine virtual or as a docker file, so that you can uses for example different databases, with out them interfering.

Besides phiscal Hard cost mony to buy and to maintain.

Last virtualisation and docker are only files, that you can simply copy to have a backup. A real maschine is a little more work, to make a backup.

But don't use XAMPP as real maschien that is exposed to the world. There much to many security risks ind teh standard configuration.